# What should the relation between the arrival and departure time of two vertices connected via cross edge in a DFT be?

Tags: algorithm

Cross Edge(a,b) is defined as an edge between two non-ancestor nodes in DFS , I studied the following relation between arrival and departure times but couldn't understand it clearly why is this true , so please clarify it .

```
arrival[b] < departure[b] < arrival[a] < departure[a]
```

Comment: are u talking about directed graphs?

Comment: No sir for undirected graphs .

Comment: Dear friend, there are no cross edges in undirected graphs.

Comment: Feel free for any more queries.

Comment: sorry sir by mistake I wrote undirected , it was for directed edges , so sorry .

Comment: Inform me, if still doubtfull.